# Source codes for apps built on Foursquare apis

Tags: android, foursquare

I've been planning to build an **Android application** built on **Foursquare APIs**. I went to the [foursquare developer site](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/) and tried out the [android oauth example](https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example). Also I noticed in the [showcase](https://developer.foursquare.com/appsshowcase/) several fancy apps such as Instgram, LocalMind. I wonder **where** (websites like github) I can find their source codes so that I can have a taste of how to develop a real foursquare app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is a direct answer to your question.. With the exception of code snippets found by google code search or regular google search, do not expect to find full source code for integration with APIs..

As far as oauth goes, there are many examples with a simple google search on how to make it work (note that you have the Venues API that does not requires the oauth process)

As far as source code goes, you should check out [this page](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries) it should have links to  **many** examples. (got [here](https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/wiki/BasicUsage) after two clicks from that page..)

From my experience, we are developing a foursquare-enabled app with a custom server software - in short, our Android app will access our server, which will access foursquare (if required) and get data and pass it to our client (Android/iPhone/whatever).

Bottom line - eventually, **you really should learn the API** yourself, know the different endpoints and the returned data structures, experiment with different search results and then, if you wonder on what is the right way to get specific data or if you think you are doing something right and getting the wrong data, this is probably the place to ask about it.
The [API Explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html) should help a lot in doing that.

Comment: Thx, I've got nothing at hand though. The page you recommend is for some reason blocked at my country.